# User Defined Function to return a result when input with multiple cells in one parameter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I created a User Defined Function which works when the two required inputs are single cells but stops working when those inputs are an array.

The function should loop through an array (Lookup_Array) and if the value in the cell is greater than 0, it should sum the values from the second array (Count_Array) in to Total.

```
Public Function Reconcile_Total(Lookup_Array As Range, Count_Array As Range) As Long

Dim Total As Long
Dim i As Integer
Total = 0
i = 1

For Each element In Lookup_Array
    If Lookup_Array > 0 Then
    Total = Total + Count_Array(i)
    Else
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next element

Reconcile_Total = Total

End Function
```

If in column A, I highlight A1:A3 as Lookup_Array and this contains 1, 0, 2 and then I highlight in column B, B1:B3 as Count_Array and this contains 100, 200, 300 the formula should return 400.

The code works if I highlight A3 and B3, it returns 300 - or if I highlight A2 and B2, it returns 0  If I highlight multiple cells like A1:A3 and B1:B3 it stops working.

I'm new to Excel VBA.

Comment: Just a note, SUMIFS will do this without the need for VBA.  `=SUMIFS(Count_Array,Lookup_Array,">0")`

Comment: BTW change the if to `If element> 0 Then`

Comment: When debugging UDF for use on a worksheet it's useful to cal lthem from a separate sub so you can debug if there's an error, instead of just getting #VALUE! on the worksheet.

Comment: ^ that. Actually the *immediate* pane (Ctrl+G) is perfect for this.